# filter product_id2 based on variant of product_id in odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-8

i have 2 fields of types many2one: product_id and product_id2, what i'm trying is to filter product_id2 and get only variants that belong to product_id.
Ex:
product(black)
product(red)
product(white)

when select product(black),filter product_id2 only with product(red) and product(white)

Comment: product_id is a relation to product.template and product_id2 is a relation to product.product?

Comment: both are a relation to product.product, i think it should be an onchange_fuction.

Comment: Thing is, that product.product doesnt have variants. product.product is the variant. What i would do is, put product_id as product.template and filter product_id2 with the variants of product_id. Anyway, if you do need both as product.product i can help you with the code. What you have to do is a domain filter in product_id2 with a function that does what you need

Comment: yes i need both as product.product, the reason behind is stock moves of product variants, so when i select one variant filter product_id2 with other variants belongs to the same product, as in example above, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a domain filter.

In the py of your model:

```
@api.onchange('product_id')
def onchange_product_id(self):

    domain = {}
    if self.product_id:
        products = self.env['product.product'].search([('product_tmpl_id', '=', self.product_tmpl_id), ('id', '!=', self.id)])

        self.product_id2 = None
        domain['product_id2'] = [('id', 'in', products.ids)]

    return {'domain': domain}
```

With that every time you select a product_id:

- Your product_id2 field will be empty.
- Your product_id2 field will be filtered only for the other variants (excluding the one that you have in product_id).

Comment: thanks dccdany, but everytime select produt_id i get the error: 'my_model' object has no attribute '_ids',
 i'm working with old api.

Comment: Why? use the new one if you are working on 8. Is this error in the line of "domain['product_id2'] = [('id', 'in', products.ids)]" ?. Anyway, i think i made a mistake in the search, it isnt self. Try with self.env['product.product']. I just modified the answer